# trying to turn a string array to ASCII number array inside of a function

Tags: arrays, matlab, double, ascii

so I tried this for the first time and I'm actually kinda proud (still new at this) but its not working completely like I would like it to.

I created a function with a for loop inside of it that takes a 1d array of any length and converts it to its hash equivalent. but it only works for numerical values and not letters or words. the arrays that I want to convert has letters as well. so I tried to convert the array inside of the function into its ascii value but it won't let me.

so here's the loop

```
function [h]=converter(array1)
double(array1)
n=length(array1);
i=1;
h=0;
for i=1:1:n
h=array1(i)+31*h;
end
end
```

[image]

instead of double (array1) I tried double('array1') but I think it assumed that I was trying to convert the input title array1
to ASCII form, is there a way of converting it inside a function or will it have to be done before the function or loop starts?

Comment: I think posting images instead of code is not welcome on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I just figured out how to add the typed code so I did that.

Comment: “It won’t let me” what does this mean? Do you get an error message when running the function? Show how you call the function, and copy-paste the full error message you get. Otherwise it’s hard to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your error, but you are using floating-point computations here. You should use integer computations with overflow to make this algorithm work. With floating-point operations, `h` will get so large at some point, that remaining letters will not change the value any more (rounding errors).

Comment: With MATLAB’s integer operations, which saturate instead of overflowing, only the last few input array elements will affect the computed value. The solution is to explicitly apply the `mod` operation.